# Почему не красит кнопку градиентом?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public Rectangle borderRectangle;
private void FlatButton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            borderRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(borderbrush, borderThickness), borderRectangle);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, (active) ? textbrush : borderbrush, borderRectangle, stringFormat);
        }
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
                {
                    base.OnPaint(e);
                    this.Paint += FlatButton_Paint;
                    using (LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(borderRectangle.Left), new Point( borderRectangle.Right), Color.FromArgb(255, 248, 140, 17), Color.FromArgb(255, 241, 99, 21)))
                    {
                      e.Graphics.FillRectangles(linGrBrush);
                    }
                }
```

Мне нужно что-бы созданная кнопка заполнялась градиентом, но почему-то выдает ошибку, в чем проблема?

Comment: "почему-то выдает ошибку" - не думаете ли Вы, что информация о том, какую ошибку "выдает", была бы большим подспорьем для желающих ответить на Ваш вопрос?

Comment: Добавил скриншот

Comment: Вы бы еще видео добавили :) Надо не скриншот, а текст.

Comment: Я нашел свою ошибку, FillRectsngles принимает два параметра, а у меня один, соответственно замена на FillRectangle(единственное число) все решила, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillrectangles(v=vs.71).aspx

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangles(linGrBrush);
```

`FillRectangles` - переводится "закрасить прямоугольники". Как эта функция должна догадаться, какие прямоугольники закрасить?

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangles(linGrBrush, new Rectangle[] { borderRectangle });
```

Comment: Дополнил основную надпись, вроде как есть указание на нужный прямоугольник

Comment: @Toxa26 Вы сходили по ссылке из ответа? Сколько параметров у функции `FillRectangles`?

Comment: Все, я нашел ошибку, FillRectsngles принимает два параметра, а у меня один, соответственно замена на FillRectangle все решила, спасибо за помощь!